# Using Windows Batch Files to Filter a TEXT File & Create 2 files: Non-Alphanumeric & Alphanumeric

Tags: windows, batch-file

Windows batch files to execute this task:

I would like to read a text file in which the variables are in quotes and are on seperate lines.

If the variable is Alphanumeric, then it goes in the Alphanumeric.txt

If the variable contains a Non-Alphanumeric character, then it goes in the Non-Alphanumeric.txt

The list is randon in length.

Thanks in advance for any responses.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve, and what have you tried?

Answer (score 1):

Use the [FINDSTR command](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490907.aspx). It supports [grep](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grep)-like pattern matching.

```
:: Find all lines matching the pattern
findstr /r ^\"[0-9A-Za-z]\"$ infile.txt > Alphanumeric.txt
:: Find all lines not matching the pattern
findstr /r /v ^\"[0-9A-Za-z]\"$ infile.txt > Non-Alphanumeric.txt
```